# Loading texture coords for OBJMesh in DirectX9/C++

Tags: c++, directx, texture-mapping, directx-9

I'm trying to get textures working on my OBJMesh loader. So far, I have looked at some online tutorials on how to do this and the most obvious example is the cube/box example which I understood. But I came across this problem where a vertex may use/have more than 1 texture coords.

For example:

```
f 711/1/1 712/2/2 709/3/3
f 711/9/1 704/10/9 712/11/2
```

As you can see, the index vertex number 711 is using texture coords number 1 and 9 and index vertex number 712 uses texture coords number 2 and 11. So my question is how do I get it to work with multiple texture coords? Is there some kind of buffer I can use like the vertex buffer and indices buffer?

I am using indices for this and I have the following vertex declarations:

```
D3DVERTEXELEMENT9 vertexElement[] = {   {0, 0, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT3, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_POSITION, 0},
                                        {0, 12, D3DDECLTYPE_FLOAT2, D3DDECLMETHOD_DEFAULT, D3DDECLUSAGE_TEXCOORD, 0},
                                        D3DDECL_END()};

device->CreateVertexDeclaration(vertexElement, &vertexDec);
```

And my here's my vertex structure:

```
struct VERTEX{
    D3DXVECTOR3 position;
    D3DXVECTOR2 uv;

    D3DCOLOR color;
};
```

not too sure what other code to show here, but if i'm missing thing or you guys need to see something to help me, let me know.

Thanks

EDIT: would it be better if I use FVF instead of vertex declarations?

Comment: No, you need to add multiple vertices with the same position and different texture coordinates to your vertex buffer.

Comment: @NicoSchertler is there seriously no way to get around this? I really can't believe that directX doesn't offer something to get around this problem...

Comment: There is really no other way.

Answer (score 0):

With DX9, you need to un-instantiate positions with split normal and texture coordinates.

Here a sample code to do it :

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <tuple>
#include <map>

struct Vec3f { /* put your beloved implementation here */ };
struct Vec2f { /* put your beloved implementation here */ };

// imagine your obj loaded as these set of vectors : 

// the vertices separate values
using Positions = std::vector<Vec3f>;
using Normals = std::vector<Vec3f>;
using Texcoords = std::vector<Vec2f>;

// and faces information
struct VertexTriplet {
    int _pos;
    int _normal;
    int _texcoord;
    friend bool operator< ( VertexTriplet const & a, VertexTriplet const & b ) {
        return    a._pos < b._pos 
               || ( a._pos == b._pos && a._normal < b._normal )
               || ( a._pos == b._pos && a._normal == b._normal && a._texcoord < b._texcoord );
    }
};

using Triangle = std::array<VertexTriplet,3>;
using Faces = std::vector<Triangle>;

// imagine your GPU friendly geometry as these two vectors
using Vertex = std::tuple<Vec3f,Vec3f,Vec2f>;
using Index = unsigned int;

using VertexBuffer = std::vector<Vertex>;
using IndexBuffer = std::vector<Index>;

using GpuObject = std::pair<VertexBuffer,IndexBuffer>;
// you can now implement the conversion :
GpuObject Convert( Positions const & positions, Normals const & normals, Texcoords const & texcoords, Faces const & faces ) {
    GpuObject result;

    // first, we create unique index for each existing triplet
    auto & indexBuffer = result.second;
    indexBuffer.reserve( faces.size() * 3 );

    std::map<VertexTriplet, Index> remap;
    Index freeIndex = 0;
    for ( auto & triangle : faces ) {
        for ( auto & vertex : triangle ) {
            auto it = remap.find( vertex );
            if ( it != remap.end() ) { // index already exists
                indexBuffer.push_back( it->second );
            } else { // create new index
                indexBuffer.push_back( freeIndex );
                remap[vertex] = freeIndex++;
            }
        }
    }

    // we now have the index buffer, we can fill the vertex buffer
    // we start by reversing the mapping from triplet to index
    // so wee can fill the memory with monotonic increasing address
    std::map< Index, VertexTriplet > reverseRemap;
    for ( auto & pair : remap ) {
        reverseRemap[pair.second] = pair.first;
    }

    auto & vertexBuffer = result.first;
    vertexBuffer.reserve( reverseRemap.size() );
    for ( auto & pair : reverseRemap ) {
        auto & triplet = pair.second;
        vertexBuffer.push_back( std::make_tuple( positions[triplet.m_pos], normals[triplet.m_normal], texcoords[triplet.m_texcoord] ) );
    }
    return result;
}
int main() {
    // read your obj file into these four vectors
    Positions positions;
    Normals normals;
    Texcoords texcoords;
    Faces faces;

    /* read the obj here */

    // then convert
    auto gpuObject = Convert( positions, normals, texcoords, faces );

    return 0;
}
```

Of course, we may imagine post processing of the index and vertex buffer to optimise performance. packing data to smaller type than float and unsigned, optimisation of the gpu post transform cache, ...

With DX10/11 we may imagine use the Faces vector as a vertex buffer providing three indices with the input layout ( vertex declaration new name ) and passing the positions, normals and texcoords as three shader resource view of buffer type to the vertex shader and perform the lookup directly. It should not be so suboptimal compared to an old school vertices interleaving but you should stick to the old school solution.